# Unable to implement two way binding for drop down which is under JQuery form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngmodel

I have `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)` attribute for a dropdown, but if I want to load any default value using `[value]` attribute my ngModel not giving the currently changed value.

I need two-way of binding on a dropdown.In general just a select dropdown its working,problem when its inside my jQuery form. Could anyone help on this?
My.Html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="state" [(ngModel)]="**myClient.address && myClient.address.state**" (ngModelChange)="getCitiesByState($event)" >
<option class="form-control"  *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]='state'>{{state.name}}
</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: aaaaaand your code is? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dropdown bound to ngModel with a default value set to "Second"/"2":

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-native-element-playground',
  template: `
  <select name="option" [(ngModel)]="option">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">
          {{ option.name }}
      </option>
  </select>
  {{option | json}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./native-element-playground.component.css']
})
export class NativeElementPlaygroundComponent {
  options = [
    { name: 'First', code: '1' },
    { name: 'Second', code: '2' },
    { name: 'Third', code: '3' }
  ];
  option = this.options[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ya in normal its binding as expected, but my dropdown inside JQuery form.